# Android : Launch Sounds At

Tags: android, timer, audio, media-player

I want to launch multiple sounds every x miliseconds with a good precision (< 5ms).

I tried `TimerTask`/`Handler.postDelayed` with `MediaPlayer`/`SoundPool`. I always have bad precision.

For instance, I launched sounds like this :

- launch sound1 in 500ms, 1000ms, 1500ms, 2000ms, 2500ms, ...
- launch sound2 in 250ms, 500ms, 750ms, 1000ms, 1250ms, 1500ms, 1750ms, ...

Do you have a better idea for this purpose ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should try AlarmManager and set it to repeat within the given time you wish

Comment: `AlarmManager` won't have any better precision, and it is not well-suited for lots of quick events like this.

Comment: Thank you very much, doc says : "Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler." (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

If I use :
handler.postDelayed(playThread, 250);
handler.postDelayed(playThread, 500);
the second line is executed few miliseconds after the first.